# What open-source, self-hosted analytics tool can I use that also supports custom APIs as data-source?

Tags: open-source, data-visualization, self-hosted, analytics

I am trying to find a free analytics tool that supports adding an API as a custom data-source.

What I need from the tool:

- good selection of possible graphs
- self-hosted
- customizability (colors, logo, etc.)
- add your own connectors (e.g. for my own API)
- open-source or free
- nice to have: ready to user officiaL docker image
- nice to have: PDF report creation
- nice to have: plugins for e.g. google analytics

It is ok for me to code my own connectors, preferably there is some kind of python or other libraries I can use to quick start my work.

So far I've come across

- Metabase
- Superset and
- Dataiku DSS

The first two were looking incredibly promising but fail when it comes down to the ability to add anything else than a SQL database.

Dataiku DSS supports everything I need but is not open source, thus has some constraints in terms of the number of users and supported technologies in the free version.